# Why does the Newman/Zagier proof of the PNT invoke complex analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, proof-explanation

I was thinking, specifically, of [this paper](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.2307/2975232/fulltext.pdf), in which Zagier offers a proof of the PNT, inspired by a paper of Newman's, the Cliffs Notes version of which would be that, first, it's fairly easy to show that

$$\left|\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\vartheta(x) - x}{x^2}dx\right| < \infty \implies \vartheta(x) \sim x$$

As well as that

$$\lim_{s\to1^+}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\vartheta(x) - x}{x^{1+s}}dx = \lim_{s\to1^+}\left(\sum\frac{((1-s)p^s - 1)\log p}{sp^s(p^s - 1)} - \frac{d}{ds}\log((s-1)\zeta(s))\right)$$

which converges.  What Zagier does from here to prove the convergence of the integral itself is that he uses a particular Tauberian theorem for a slightly rewritten integral, whose preconditions take a fair amount of complex analysis to justify.

What I was wondering was, from this step, since the absolute value of the integrand will at every point be increasing as $s$ decreases, couldn't you prove its convergence more easily with the monotone convergence theorem?  Since Zagier is a world-famous mathematician and I collect academic suspensions like expensive pogs, I'm guessing the answer is "no," but I'd like to know why.

Comment: Do you have an upper bound on the integral, uniform in $s$, to use when invoking the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: You can use the dominated convergence theorem with dominating function $\frac{\vartheta(x) - x}{x^2}$ but only once you know $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\vartheta(x) - x}{x^2}dx$ converges. Proving the PNT is much more complicated, and we need to use that $\vartheta(x)$ is increasing and has bounded (discrete) variations and that $\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} + \frac{1}{s-1}$ is analytic on $Re(s) \ge 1$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_tauberian_theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Ikehara_theorem

Comment: @user1952009, I'm not totally sure what you're trying to say.  Once it's shown that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\vartheta(x) - x}{x^2}dx$ converges, we're done, the fact that $\vartheta(x) \sim x$ following very quickly from the high-school divergence of $\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x}$ (see art. VI of the linked paper).  The theorem used by Zagier to show this convergence is similar to the Wiener-Ikehara theorem, but a little easier.

Comment: Your question is if we can use the monotone convergence theorem. 1st of all no we can't because $\theta(x)-x$ changes of sign infinitely often. And we can use the dominated convergence theorem with dominating function $\frac{|\theta(x)-x|}{x^2}$ but only once we showed that $\int_1^\infty \frac{|\theta(x)-x|}{x^2}dx < \infty$. Do you have any other question ?

Comment: And you should use instead [$\psi(x) = \sum_{n < x} \Lambda(n) = \sum_{p^k < x} \ln p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch) such that $\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \Lambda(n) n^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty \psi(x) x^{-s-1}dx$. The PNT is that $\psi(x) \sim x$ and the RH that $\psi(x)-x = O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$

Comment: I see now why I can't use the monotone convergence theorem, but why would I use the dominated convergence theorem when the precondition I'd need has already gotten me to what I set out to prove?  And why would I use $\psi(x)$ at all, since trivially $\psi(x) \sim \vartheta(x)$?  Zagier doesn't.  If it's because "that's what the PNT is," surely more common than either is $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$.

Answer (score 3):

The monotone convergence theorem requires monotone - the integrand should, as a function of $s$, be monotonic in the same direction for all $x$ - convergence, it is not sufficient that the absolute value is monotonically increasing at each point. Consider

$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}\cos x\,dx = \frac{s}{1+s^2}$$

for $s > 0$. Clearly the absolute value of the integrand is increasing at each point for $s \to 0$, and the limit of the integrals also exists (and is $0$), but of course

$$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_0^a \cos x\,dx$$

does not exist.

The existence of

$$\lim_{s \searrow 0} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx} f(x)\,dx$$

is the integration analogue of [Abel summability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation) for series, and just like not all Abel-summable series are convergent, not all Abel-integrable functions are improperly Riemann-integrable.

Newman's theorem gives a - relatively mild - sufficient condition for the existence of the improper Riemann integral. Conversely, if $f$ is a bounded function such that the improper Riemann integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$$

exists, then it is not too hard (but on the other hand neither is it obvious) to show that the holomorphic function defined for $\operatorname{Re} s > 0$ by

$$F(s) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}f(x)\,dx \tag{$\ast$}$$

cannot have a meromorphic continuation with a pole on the imaginary axis. Thus Newman's theorem does in some sense not require "much" more than necessary.

To see that $F$ as defined in $(\ast)$ cannot have poles on the imaginary axis if the improper integral of $f$ exists, one shows that for every fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}$ one has $\lim\limits_{\sigma \searrow 0} \sigma\cdot F(\sigma + it) = 0$. For $y \geqslant 0$ define

$$R(y) := \int_y^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$$

and $S(y) = \sup \:\{ \lvert R(x)\rvert : x \geqslant y\}$, and integrate by parts in $(\ast)$:

\begin{align}
F(s) &= \int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}\bigl(-R'(x)\bigr)\,dx \\
&= \bigl(-e^{-sx}R(x)\bigr)\biggr\rvert_0^{\infty} - s\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}R(x)\,dx \\
&= R(0) - s\int_0^{\infty} e^{-sx}R(x)\,dx\,.
\end{align}

(Although $R$ is in general not differentiable everywhere, so replacing $f(x)$ by $-R'(x)$ is not valid everywhere, the integration by parts is correct.) Then for fixed $t \in \mathbb{R}$, all $\sigma > 0$ and arbitrary $y \in (0,\infty)$ one has

\begin{align}
\lvert \sigma F(\sigma + it)\rvert
&\leqslant \sigma \lvert R(0)\rvert + \lvert\sigma + it\rvert\cdot \sigma \int_0^{\infty} e^{- \sigma x} \lvert R(x)\rvert\,dx \\
&\leqslant \sigma \lvert R(0)\rvert + \sigma\lvert \sigma + it\rvert \int_0^y \lvert R(x)\rvert\,dx + S(y)\lvert \sigma + it\rvert \underbrace{\int_y^{\infty} \sigma e^{-\sigma x}\,dx}_{{} = e^{-\sigma y}}
\end{align}

and therefore

$$\limsup_{\sigma \searrow 0} \lvert \sigma F(\sigma + it)\rvert \leqslant S(y)\lvert t\rvert.$$

Since $\lim_{y \to \infty} S(y) = 0$, the assertion follows.